# "Affine" algebraic spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $I$ be a small category, $i\mapsto R_i$ a functor from $I$ to commutative rings with identity and $X$ a scheme. Since for every $i$ we have a morphism $\text{Spec}R_i\to\text{Spec}\lim_i R_i$, we obtain a natural map
$$\text{Hom}(\text{Spec}\lim_iR_i,X)\to\lim_i\text{Hom}(\text{Spec}R_i,X)$$
If $X=\text{Spec}A$ is affine, then
$$\text{Hom}(\text{Spec}\lim_iR_i,\text{Spec}A)=\text{Hom}(A,\lim_iR_i)=\lim_i(A,R_i)=\lim_i\text{Hom}(\text{Spec}R_i,\text{Spec}A)$$
and hence the map above is bijective. Things start to become interesting when we observe that also the converse is true: if the map above is bijective for every small limit of rings, then $X$ is affine.

In fact, suppose that $X$ is such that the map above is bijective for every small limit of rings, and let $X=\bigcup_i\text{Spec} A_i$ be an open affine covering, and $\text{Spec} A_i\cap\text{Spec} A_j=\bigcup_{k}\text{Spec}A_{ijk}$ an affine covering of the intersections. By a small abuse of notation, this allows us to write $X$ as a colimit $\text{colim}_i\text{Spec} A_i$ of affine schemes. On the other hand, we have that the limit $\lim_i A_i$ is naturally the global sections $\Gamma(X)$. Hence we have natural identifications
$$\text{Hom}(\text{Spec}\Gamma(X),X)=\text{Hom}(\text{Spec}\lim_iA_i,X)=\lim_i\text{Hom}(\text{Spec}A_i,X)=$$
$$=\text{Hom}(\text{colim}_i\text{Spec}A_i,X)=\text{Hom}(X,X)$$
In particular, we obtain a natural map $\text{Spec}\Gamma(X)\to X$ which is easily checked to be inverse to $X\to\text{Spec}\Gamma(X)$.

The interesting thing is that this weird criterion for affinity can be imposed to a much larger class of objects than schemes, for example it can be applied to algebraic spaces. Hence, let us call an algebraic space affine if it satisfies the criterion above.

**Vague question:** What are affine algebraic spaces? Have they ever been studied?

**Precise question 1:** Does it exist an affine algebraic space which is not a scheme?

**Precise question 2:** If the answer to question n.1 is yes, can we 
 find a Zariski cover of an algebraic space with affine algebraic spaces?

This question is the result of my nocturnal thoughts about my yesterday's question [Extension of local morphism in algebraic spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297115/extension-of-local-morphism-in-algebraic-spaces)

Comment: For an algebraic space $X$, you still have a presentation with some ${\rm Spec}\, A_i$, but with etale rather than Zariski transition maps. But this shouldn't matter for your argument since $\mathcal{O}_X$ is also a sheaf for the etale topology. So your argument should prove that $X={\rm Spec}\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$, so $X$ is an affine scheme. Am I missing something?

Comment: I guess you are missing nothing: you are correct, and I am dumb. Maybe one could modify the definition of affine algebraic space requiring the criterion only for those systems whose transition maps are Zariski open embeddings, but it seems a strange definition.